# Javascript code to write JQGrid data to excelsheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom

I am working on JQGrid, I found one solution but it is writing whole JQGrid on excelsheet. But I only want JQGrid data on excelsheet. My JQGrid data consists of sharepoint list data. So can anybody share some code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

function JSONToCSVConvertor() {
    var JSONData = JQGridJSON;
    ReportTitle = "Employee Details";
    ShowLabel = true;

```
var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

var CSV = '';    
//Set Report title in first row or line

CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

//This condition will generate the Label/Header
if (ShowLabel) {
    var row = "";

    //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
    for (var index in arrData[0]) {

        //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
        row += index + ',';
    }

    row = row.slice(0, -1);

    //append Label row with line break
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
}

//1st loop is to extract each row
for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    var row = "";

    //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
    for (var index in arrData[i]) {
        row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
    }

    row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

    //add a line break after each row
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
}

if (CSV == '') {        
    alert("Invalid data");
    return;
}   

//Generate a file name
var fileName = "MyReport_";
//this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

//Initialize file format you want csv or xls
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

// Now the little tricky part.
// you can use either>> window.open(uri);
// but this will not work in some browsers
// or you will not get the correct file extension    

//this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
var link = document.createElement("a");    
link.href = uri;

//set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
link.style = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = fileName + ".csv";

//this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

}​​